# How do I properly call setCenterCoordinate?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I've included MapKit.h and I have the prototype declared in the .h file of the object mapView that I'm using it with:

```
- (void)setCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

This is how I'm calling it in my .m:

```
setCenterCoordinate:userLocation animated:FALSE;
```

But it keeps pointing at the semicolon and saying "Expected ']'"

If someone can let me know what I'm doing wrong it would br greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `setCenterCoordinate:animated:` is a map view method.  Why are you declaring it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you subclassed MKMapView? If not then you need to tell the map view object to setCenterCoordinate

```
[yourMapViewObject setCenterCoordinate:userLocation animated:FALSE];
```

If you have then you don't need to redeclare setCenterCoordinate:animated: in your .h, and you probably shouldn't be overriding it either. Maybe some more code from the top of your .h or .m would help clarify the situation.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. Forgot I needed square brackets around the method call and forgot I had to call it in relation to my map object.

Answer (score 0):

`[self setCenterCoordinate:userLocation animated:NO];`

In Objective-C you send messages to objects in order to ask them to act. Your declaration of `setCenterCoordinate:animated:` declares that your class responds to that message.

When you're within a method implementation, `self` is always a pointer to the current object. So the method above posts that message to the current object.